# What do we call "a person who blames others for things they didn't do"?

Tags: word-request, definition

What do we call "**a person who blames others for things they didn't do**"?

I searched on the web, and found the word "**blamer**". I know what it means, and I don't find it fits the definition I wrote.

Update: It can mean "**false accusation**" and/or "**When somebody says that another did something (wrong) when they haven't**".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a related word, *scapegoat*, which means:

> **[scapegoat](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/scapegoat)** (*noun*) A person who is blamed for the wrongdoings, mistakes, or faults of others, especially for reasons of expediency.

From this word, we have the word *scapegoater*, which means:

> [**scapegoater**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scapegoater) one that makes a scapegoat of something or somebody

While *scapegoat* is fairly common in the vernacular, I think *scapegoater* is a less common word. However, it fits what you are looking for.

Here's a usage of it in print:

> Tolerance and independent thinking are essential to a democratic form of government, but the scapegoater cannot think straight.
>
> (Charles Henry Scherf, *Do You Own Thinking*, 1946)

Another book about hostilities in the workplace says:

> A scapegoater is one who transfers blame to persons or groups, who are not necessarily guilty, in order to focus attention away from those who are actually responsible — sometimes from themselves.
>
> (J.A. Wambach & R.W. Fuller, *Battles between somebodies and nobodies: stop abuse of rank at work and at home*, 2008)

Comment: Tasneem: I'm glad you like this answer, but you should wait a little longer before accepting. [Here's why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: Ok, I will wait. And, I will read the article. Thank you for the answer, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I found [imputer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imputer).

> Noun[edit]
>
> **imputer** (plural imputers)
>
> One who imputes.

**Impute**, as a verb, means:

> 1. to attribute or ascribe (something dishonest or dishonourable, esp a criminal offence) to a person

Note: I am not a native speaker, so I can't comment on how commonly it's used.

Comment: It's an obscure word – but so is the word that I proffered. It's still a good find, though.

Comment: I’ve never heard “impute” outside a legal context, and I’ve never heard “imputer” at all, though I’d figure out what it meant.

Answer (score 1):

It's also called framing or malicious slander. Malicious slander is the attempt to discredit someone. You can be sued for doing so.